# How would I create a windowless app using python on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: python, ubuntu, user-interface, pygtk, desktop-application

I've spent literally all day on google, stackoverflow, and many other sites trying to find a way to implement a windowless app using python, to no avail. I'm familiar with python and have been using pygtk to create previous apps, but it doesn't look like pygtk can cut it.

I'm using the standard Ubuntu 12.10 Unity setup, and don't want to switch over to something that uses compiz. I also don't want to use screenlets.

The app I want to create is to notify me of any updates on my social media accounts, and I want it to be floating perpetually on the screen, accessible at any time. I want it to be stand-alone, and not be dependent on outside apps (like screenlets) to run, and I want it to be as minimalistic as possible.

If I can't accomplish this with pygtk, what else should I use? If it is possible, how would I go about implementing it?

Answer (score 0):

BTW Unity is COMPIZ plugin :D

Also I think that PyGTK will not be able to do it. You'd need some kind of desktop plugin, but what are you trying to do is tricky, it may break in future versions of Unity - you need to use the desktop manager (wm) to manage that as a borderless window with static position, somethink like desktop plugins in KDE. Also it will not work in other wm's.

Maybe you should consider making it a simple icon in the notification area that would change and on hover it would display more info.. that I'm sure would work anywhere.